# Calculate the maximum value of the complex modulous |v-u|

Tags: complex-numbers

I was asked to sketch the complex where 
$|u-1+i| = 2$ and $|v-(3+5i)|=1$ on the same diagram
then I was asked to find the maximum value of |v-u|

What is $|v-u|$ basically ? how am I going to visualize it in the diagram ?

Comment: Which diagram did you find for u and which diagram did you find for v?

Comment: u should be a circle with centre (1,-1) and a rad of 2

Comment: v is also a circle with centre (4,5) and a radius of 1

Comment: And if you draw these two circles on the same diagram, you cannot fathom where the distance |u-v| from u on the first circle to v on the second circle, is maximum?

Comment: well not really ,,

Comment: ?? Hint: Everything occurs on the line where the two centers lie.

Comment: so basically I find that line assuming its the modulous of a right triangle with sides (6) and 3 ?

Comment: which is basically radical 45 + 1 + 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,\omega_1=1-\mathrm i$ be the centre of the first circle, $\,\omega_2=3+5\mathrm i$ the centre of the second circle, $\,z_1, z_2\,$  the outer points of intersection of the centres line with the circles (those *not* between $\,\omega_1\,$ and $\,\omega_2$).

By the triangle inequality, we have:
$$\lvert v-u\rvert\le \lvert v-\omega_2\rvert+\lvert\omega_2-\omega_1\rvert+\lvert \omega_1-u\rvert=3+2\sqrt{10}.$$
Noow, it results from the equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, this bound is attained at $u=t_1,\enspace v=t_2$, hence it is the maximum modulus.